# Issue when accessing const value in Laravel blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

**Lang**

```
"Min_UserName" =>  "Min :chars chars for username",
```

**JQuery**

```
$("form#registerForm").validate({
    rules: {
        UserName: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6
        }
    },
    messages: {
        UserName: {
            required:  "{!! trans('Register.Required_UserName') !!}",
            minlength: "{!! trans('Register.Min_UserName', 
                                      ['chars' => '\App\UserMinValue::Min_UserName']) !!}"
        }
    }
});
```

**Class**

```
namespace App\Architecture\MinMaxValues;

class UserMinValue {
    const Min_UserName = 6;
}
```

**Current Output**

```
minlength:  "Min App\UserMinValue::Min_UserName chars for username",
```

**Expected Output**

```
minlength:  "Min 6 chars for username",
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a quote around the Class path so string path is sent out and not the value you need, change:

```
['chars' => '\App\UserMinValue::Min_UserName']
```

To:

```
['chars' => \App\UserMinValue::Min_UserName]
```